# Janela Modal BootStrap não exibe estilos nos componentes - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou com um problema no qual não consigo resolver há meses! Estou usando um package de estilos bootStrap e JS, no qual os referencieiem minha _Layout. Em todas as pages que são renderizadas e que herdam da page Principal, tudo funciona sem problemas. Bastou eu abrir as janelas em modal, que os problemas começaram a surgir... Observem que o DropDown situado na page Index é estilizado corretamente, mas o mesmo dropdown situado na view Create não funciona.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para que minhas modals funcionem, meu controlador retorna uma View "Create", mas quando ela é carregada no modal (Situado na Index), eu preciso jogar null para a propriedade Layout, senão a janela não abre. (Isso poderia ser um problema).
Já tentei abrir as Modals usando PartialViews, mas também não funciona...

Vou deixar o link para quem quiser dar uma olhada no projeto:
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=40838E65B9F8787E%21120&cid=40838E65B9F8787E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, ocorreu um problema parecido mas usando o componente datepicker e select2, adicionei na partial para poder resolver esse problema.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.select2').select2();

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        language: 'pt-BR',
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Adriano Praia... Infelizmente, não funcionou....

Answer (score 1):

Pessoa, após muita pesquisa desgastante e paciência encontrei a solução neste site: [Resolução do Problema](https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems)

Bastou eu adicionar o script abaixo:

```js
<script>
    $('#mySelect2').selectpicker({
        dropdownParent: $('#modalGenerica')
    });
</script>
```

Portanto, a resposta do companheiro @Adriano Praia foi a mais próxima.

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

O teu problema de CSS,

deve aumentar o z-index do elemento do modal

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @ Nuno Maximiano, mas como eu faço isso?

Comment: no ficheiro de css que carregas deves adicionar algo do género

`.form-horizontal{
z-index:99999;
}`

mas isso vai afectar todos os form com esta class

 ou directamente na div adicionas `style="z-index:99999;"`

Comment: aconselho primeiro adicionares directamente no modal o elemento style para testares e depois se der passas para a css, mas deves criar uma ou um id para o modal ou class para não rescreveres todas os elementos com a class '.form-horizontal'

Comment: Não funcionou :(